# React Native Images + Authorization Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reactjs, react-native

I have an Image URL that I need to send with an authorization request to be able to fetch it. I'm not sure how to do this with React Native's Image component. I understand that I can put the URL as the URI in the `<Image/>` object but that doesn't work because of the need to authorize.

So something like

```
<Image
    source={THE_URL} // how do i include authorization headers here?
/>
```

I'd rather not manually get the image binary and then render.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done, but I'd love to be proven wrong. You may be able to `fetch()`, save to disk, then pass the path into the require statement. I'm totally grasping. Good luck

Comment: Seems like authorization might be able to work using query string parameters. I'll update once I experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out pre-signed URLs are a thing - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Confirmed it works.

Comment: Could you post the code you used to make your put request? I've been having a nightmare of a time making image put requests from react native with presigned urls

Comment: Yeah I'll add a gist tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: Did you get a chance to make that gist?

Comment: Hey got delayed - will get to it. but this is the reference implementation I used. I compared my output with its output line by line. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html

Comment: This will break the caching of the Image component.

Comment: Have you by any chance finished that gist file?

Comment: Don't have the time. Go line by line in the link that I have on there, compare the output between their python and your JS; it will work.